# Adding labels to some datapoints in seaborn regression plot given condition

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

Here is a table:

```
dict1 = {'left':[7,3,5,10,9],
         'right':[2,17,0,8,1]}
table = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

I've created a regression scatter plot (scatterplot with best fit line):

```
sns.regplot(x=table['right'], y=table['left'], data=table)
```

I would like to add labels to datapoints in the plot where values are => 10 in either columns. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the x,y pairs and if any are >=10 add that text to the chart at those coordinates, with an offset of +/- .5 so it doesn't land on the dot.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dict1 = {'left':[7,3,5,10,9],
         'right':[2,17,0,8,1]}
table = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

ax = sns.regplot(x=table['right'], y=table['left'], data=table)

for x in table.values:
    if any([n>=10 for n in x]):
        ax.text(x=x[1]+.5, y=x[0]-.5, s=','.join(map(str,reversed(x))))
```

[image]